# R dplyr if date difference is less

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    date = c(as.Date("2022-03-01"), as.Date("2022-03-02"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-04-01"), as.Date("2022-04-10"))
    )
```

My goal is to create new column in dplyr and assign 1/0 depending on date difftime in days. In case that difference is lower than 7, 0 schould be assigned and vice versa. Thus desired result is.

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    date = c(as.Date("2022-03-01"), as.Date("2022-03-02"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-04-01"), as.Date("2022-04-10")),
    cache = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `diff`. It works because objects of class `"Date"` record the integer number of days since an origin and are internally integers.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

dt <-
  data.frame(
    date = c(as.Date("2022-03-01"), as.Date("2022-03-02"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-04-01"), as.Date("2022-04-10"))
  )

dt %>%
  mutate(cache = c(0, diff(date) >= 7L))
#>         date cache
#> 1 2022-03-01     0
#> 2 2022-03-02     0
#> 3 2022-03-08     0
#> 4 2022-03-08     0
#> 5 2022-04-01     1
#> 6 2022-04-10     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

Following the exchange of comments, the code below seems to be the right one.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

dt <-
  data.frame(
    date = c(as.Date("2022-03-01"), as.Date("2022-03-02"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-03-08"), as.Date("2022-04-01"), as.Date("2022-04-10"))
  )

dt %>%
  mutate(
    cache = as.integer(date - first(date) >= 7L)
  )
#>         date cache
#> 1 2022-03-01     0
#> 2 2022-03-02     0
#> 3 2022-03-08     1
#> 4 2022-03-08     1
#> 5 2022-04-01     1
#> 6 2022-04-10     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Note:

In the creation of the dates vector, it would have been simpler to call `as.Date` only once.

```
as.Date(c("2022-03-01", "2022-03-02", "2022-03-08", "2022-03-08", "2022-04-01", "2022-04-10"))
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for reply. Result is actually different than mine, maybe I should explain better that I once row is evaluated as cache 0 all upcoming rows should be labeled with 1 until time difference is greater than 7. In other words for 2022-03-01, first greater date is 2022-03-08, than I would like to mark cached 0 all rows where time sifference between 2022-03-08 is less than 7

Comment: @prdel99 But then the last 2 rows will have cache equal to 1, their time difference from 2022-03-08 is greater than 7. This doesn't match your posted output.

Comment: You are right both 2022-04-01 and 2022-04-10 shouls be marked by one by also 2022-03-08 since time difference between 2022-03-01 and 2022-03-08 is greater than 7

Comment: @prdel99 See if the edit solves it.